# Display the name of the product inside the <h3> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, backbone.js

1. I am learning angular js
2. I am doing small tasks..
3. but I am getting this error **Display the name of the product inside
   the  tag.**
4. can you tell me how to fix it
5. providing my code below

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="gemStore">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
    <div class="product row">
      <h3>
        {{store.product.name}}
        <em class="pull-right"></em>
      </h3>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

js

```
(function(){
  var gem = { name: 'Azurite', price: 2.95 };
  var app = angular.module('gemStore', []);
  app.controller('StoreController',function(){
    this.product = gem;
  });
})();
```

Comment: is this code school?

Comment: @SandroEric i am just learning...

Comment: Sorry. I meant no offense. I'm just asking if you're working with the  codeschool.com material?

Comment: @mapuut you have to load all angularjs scripts before using ng-app

Comment: Your code is working fine here is the fiddle of it http://jsfiddle.net/w2fzfuho/

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `$scope`:

```
app.controller('StoreController',function($scope){
    $scope.product = gem;
});

{{product.name}}
```

Please try the following snippet.

```js
(function(){
  var gem = { name: 'Azurite', price: 2.95 };
  var app = angular.module('gemStore', []);
  app.controller('StoreController',function($scope){
    $scope.product = gem;
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="gemStore">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="StoreController">
    <div class="product row">
      <h3>
        {{product.name}}
        <em class="pull-right"></em>
      </h3>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```